# Why is any power of $(X_1, X_2,...,X_i)$ primary in $k[X_1, X_2,...,X_n]$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

How to prove that all the powers of the ideals $(X_1, X_2,...,X_i)$ are primary in $ k[X_1, X_2,...,X_n]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** Prove that if $I$ is primary in $R$ then $I[X]$ is primary in $R[X]$. (This reduces your problem to the case $i=n$ and this is easy.)

Comment: I am here giving the details of the proof:(X1) is and primary ideal in K[X1] is obvious because (X1) is an maximal ideal in K[X1].

Now using the above mentioned result one concludes (X1)[X2] is primary in (K[X1])[X2]=k[X1,X2]

One can show easily (keeping it in mind (X1)={f.X1:f∈K[X1]})

(X1)[X2]=(X1) in k[X1,X2]

So we have proved that (X1) is and primary ideal in K[X1,X2]

Inductively we can prove (X1) is and primary ideal in K[X1,X2,...,Xn]

To prove (X1,X2,...,Xi) is primary in K[X1,X2,...,Xn] start the fact that (X1,X2,...,Xi) is primary in K[X1,X2,...,Xi] and repeat the same process.